# WriteString does not keep the input format for a^2 + b^3?

Tags: output-formatting, files-and-directories, text

I have a series of expression which is added one by one, not all at once, to a file (**OUT.nb**). for some of them that has POWER format (a^2 + b^3 ), **WriteString** cannot write it correct. Also I tried **Write** but it adds every expression in one single line. The problem is after all writing completion, I need to **read/evaluate** the **OUT.nb** file but with those problems it does not work for me. **If the content could be written all in a single line then it would be great and works for me.**

So I tried multiple ways for my code which is ***called a few times*** and writes into that file(in each iteration one expression is written to the file,):

```
Write[file,expr]; 
WriteString[file," && "];
```

the content of file is (writeString does not write power expression correctly),

```
 k >= kP
 && 7^k*(-7 - 6*y) == 7^kP*(-7 - 6*yP)
 &&  Not[ iP != jP ]
```

so far so good but when I want to read it or evaluate it it does not work fine:

```
nbb = NotebookOpen[
   FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "MathematicaOutputInvR.nb"}], 
   Visible -> False];
LF1 = NotebookEvaluate[nbb, InsertResults -> True]
NotebookClose[nbb];
```

**The output is : iP==jP**

and if I read the file it returns:

```
filename = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "MathematicaOutputInvR.nb"}];
LF1 = Read[filename]
Close[filename];
```

**k>=kP , the first line only.**

Also import a text is not evaluable

```
LF1 = Import[filename,"Text"];
Close[filename];
```

please help me as I need it. Thanks

Comment: Use ``Write[file, ToString[expr, InputForm]]`` to export your expression(s). Then use ``ToExpression[StringDelete[ReadString["test.txt"], "\n" | "\r"]]`` to get it back. As you can read in [`WriteString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html), it uses ``OutputForm``, which is not suitable for parsing. That is why you have to export it to ``InputForm`` which can be parsed again.

Comment: thanks , but  where and when should I use ToExpression? you mean instead of Read? could you give me the full answer as I am new to Wolfram. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation for [`WriteString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html), it uses `OutputForm` of the expression, which is not suitable for importing. That is why you have to export it with `InputForm` which can be parsed again. To convert a string into an expression, use `ToExpression`.

```
expr1 = a^2 > b;
expr2 = 2 b < c^3;
expr3 = d == e;

filename = "test.txt";

file = File[filename];
WriteString[file, ToString[expr1, InputForm]];
WriteString[file, "&&"];
WriteString[file, ToString[expr2, InputForm]];
WriteString[file, "&&"];
WriteString[file, ToString[expr3, InputForm]];
Close[file];

expr = ToExpression[ReadString[filename]]

(* a^2 > b && 2 b < c^3 && d == e *)
```

You could also first build the whole expression directly, and export it just once with `Export`.

```
expr = And@@ {expr1, expr2, expr3};
Export[filename, expr];
```